# C# custom mask for textbox

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

I know there is masked textbox component for C#, but what I need is to create masked text box which requires entered text in format: LLL/LLL but when I enter such mask into Mask property in preview and mask I see separator "." but not "/" as I want to have. Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The / character is the date separator character in the mask.  What you'll actually get depends on your culture preferences.  To get a literal `/` you'll have to escape it with a `\`.  Like this:

```
        this.maskedTextBox1.Mask = @"LLL\/LLL";
```

Don't use the @ when you use the Properties window.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this clue
there is one more problem in maskedtextbox  that is when the system short date changes the mask also changes for example..

**Before**

```
System date : d/M/yy  
Mask Format : __/__/__
```

**After**

```
System date : d-M-yy  
Mask Format : __-__-__
```

Using escape char hepled me.

Just add escape char in mask. For example:

```
textbox1.Mask = 00/\00/\00
```